# No method write found in TcpStream in rust

Tags: rust

I have this code that initializes an http server,

```
use std::net::TcpListener;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:5000");
    if listener.is_err() {
        println!(
            "Some error occured while initializing the server {}",
            listener.unwrap_err()
        );
        return;
    }

    let listener = listener.unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        if stream.is_err() {
            println!(
                "Some error occured while listening to incoming connections {}",
                stream.unwrap_err()
            );
            return;
        }
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
        let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
        stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        stream.flush().unwrap();
    }
}
```

So in `stream.write` it says `no method named write found for struct std::net::TcpStream in the current scope`. Same with `stream.flush`. Why is that?

Comment: Did you import `std::io::Write`?